# Wordpress Site Loading Speed to Slow: 8.13s

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed

My wordpress website is extremely slow on loading the page. It's takin 8.3 seconds from Frankfurt sometimes more.

I am using Bluehost and I have heard it's slower but this seems too much...

You can see the waterfall here:
https://tools.pingdom.com/#5a253be0d4c00000

I noticed it has huge waiting times for the main page...

I have tried multiple things but had no success in bringing it down.

I am now using W3Cache but it's not helping much..., the loading speed is much the same. I have used it on other sites before with better results...

I have also changed most of the images by .jpg images that I optimized.

Does any one have any ideas or what I can do to bring the loading speed down to at least 4s? It's 8s right now
And any intel on why this is happening and how I can solve it would be great!

Comment: Hi there! Since this question isn't about programming but more about site speed / SEO, you might want to ask here instead: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are loading 45 .js and 25 .css (!!!) I think you'll benefit a lot from a merge and minify.

I like Autooptimize plugin for that, but you'll probly need some manual tweaking as well.

You should always move all possible JS to footer (last parameter from `wp_enqueue_script`), because `<head>` script load blocks rendering.

You could edit out useless loads or unused parts from files.
Like, you're loading `font-awesome.css` and their font files with ~4k icons twice (once in theme and again in a chat plugin).

You're loading a complete `animate.css` with it's ~80 animations code, just to use 1 or 2...

Also identify some css and js that are not needed for home and manually block them from ever loading on home making that page load faster...

```
// functions.php

if(is_home()) {
    dequeue_style('handle')
    dequeue_script('handle')
}
```

Comment: Hi Rodrigo thanks for your answer. I have already tried autooptimize and it broke the website. It probably had some conflict with wp members so I had to remove it. I noticed that the problem seems to be in the waiting time/yellow. So using that function I can block some css and some js files from loading? do I insert the link in the 'handle'?

Comment: In Advanced Options of autooptimize you can tweak it in order to [Exclude scripts from Autoptimize], etc...

'handle' is the internal alias of the script. To load a script in wordpress you (or your plugins) you assign it a handle when you use wp_enqueue_script(...)

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Thanks for the info Rodrigo. Will be trying this.